# Is this tree perhaps a mespilus?

Tags: identification, trees

Fruit is 1 inch diameter. Public area, zone 7. Very showy. Bark as if exfoliating, in a beautiful way. Fruit partially falling.

It looks mature, at least 20 years old. 20-25 ft high.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be Crataegus pedicellata - need a better image of the foliage really. Its definitely not either of the plants commonly known as Mespillus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see if this might fit the bill...Crataegus douglasii, a Hawthorn.  [Crataegus douglasii](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Crataegus_douglasii_kz5.jpg)

Comment: Agree Crataegus - not sure its douglasii though, that has black berries... Vote given for Crataegus ID though!

Comment: Hey, I am fine with that, Bamboo.  Getting down to species and variety...ugh!  You figure that one out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the extra pics. I think it probably is Crataegus pedicellata https://futureforests.ie/products/crataegus-pedicellata but time will tell - its leaves turn red in autumn before they fall.

I'm not sure how healthy the tree is - the bark isn't exfoliating, it's falling off, which sometimes indicates a problem with the tree. If it's on your property, keep an eye on it, it may become unsafe over time.